# I'm having trouble with my C++ program using arrays/functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function

For my class, I am needing to write a program using arrays instead of individual variables that contain the score. Struggling with this chapter. I'll leave my code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Needing to find the sum between all of the scores entered, subtract the highest and lowest and then find the average.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// Function prototypes

void getJudgeData(double, double);
double calcScore(double);
double findLowest(double);
double findHighest(double);

int main()
{
// Declare variables

    const int SIZE = 7;
    double scores[SIZE];
    double sum;
    
    for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
        double getJudgeData(scores[x]);
    
    
    return 0;
}

// Function getJudgeData

void getJudgeData(double &judgeScore, double scores[])
{
    static int judge = 1;
    cout << "Enter score " << judge << ": ";
    cin >> judgeScore;
    while (judgeScore < 0 || judgeScore > 10)
    {
        cout << "Invalid score, please enter a score between 0 and 10";
        cout << "Enter score " << judge << ": ";
        cin >> judgeScore;
    }
    judge++;

    return;
}

// Function calcScore

double calcScore(double scores[])
{
    double highest = findHighest(scores);
    double lowest = findLowest(scores);
    double result = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
    {
        result += scores[x];
    }       

    
    result - findHighest(scores) - findLowest(scores);



    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "The average after the dropping the highest and lowest scores: " << result / 5 << endl;

    return result;
}

// Function findLowest

double findLowest(double scores[])
{
    double result = 10;
    for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
    {
        if (scores[x] < result)
            result = scores[x];
    }
    return result;
}

// Function findHighest

double findHighest(double scores[])
{
    double result = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
    {
        if (scores[x] > result)
            result = scores[x];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your function prototypes should match the signatures. For example: `void getJudgeData(double, double);` and `void getJudgeData(double &judgeScore, double scores[])` do not match.

Comment: You have a lot of errors and warnings in what you posted. You should copy and paste what you are compiling.